# Determining the fourth term of $c_k = kc_{k-1}^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

What is the fourth term of the following recursively defined sequence?

$c_k = kc_{k-1}^2$ for integers $k \ge 1$ and $c_0 = 1$.

The possible answers are $12$ and $20$. I am not sure which one it is and how to decide this.

Comment: First of all, don't shout. Second of all, can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: you can make sub- and superscripts by using _ and ^ respectively. I assume you mean $c_k = k(c_k - 1)^2$?

Comment: I suspect the OP means to write $c_k = k(c_{k-1})^2$, with $k\geq 1$ and $c_0 = 1$.

Comment: Can you use the definition to find $c_1$? $c_2$? $c_3$? It seems strange that the _fourth_ term in particular would cause problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

You mean $c_k = k(c_{k-1})^2$?

$c_0 = 1$

$c_1 = 1 \times c_0^2 = 1 \times 1^2 = 1$

$c_2 = 2 \times c_1^2 = 2 \times 1^2 = 2$

$c_3 = 3 \times c_2^2 = 3 \times 2^2 = 12$

$c_4 = 4 \times c_3^2 = 4 \times 12^2 = 576$

...